# How do I open google chrome in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried to do various python codes but I cannot find any that work on my PC.

```
def UI():
os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
choice1=input("Pick a program: ")
if choice1=='Google':   
 ('https://www.google.com/')
```

That is all I have come up with

If anybody has any answers please tell me

Comment: Here is an approach: https://pythonexamples.org/python-open-url-in-chrome-browser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.system('start chrome')` and `os.system('start chrome {}'.format(site))` in Windows or `os.system('google-chrome')` and `os.system('google-chrome {}'.format(site))` in Linux, where `site` is URL for the site you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

```
import webbrowser

url = 'http://docs.python.org/'

# MacOS
chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

# Windows
# chrome_path = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe %s'

# Linux
# chrome_path = '/usr/bin/google-chrome %s'

webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

You can call get() with the path to Chrome. Below is an example - replace chrome_path with the correct path for your platform.